# Derived method 'RequiresWebPartClientScript' in type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermProperty' error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, configuration-wizard

I have a SharePoint 2013 server (15.0.4420.1017) which is RTM release. A few days ago IS guys installed Windows updates on this server and now I am getting following error when I try to open any site or central administration.

> Derived method 'RequiresWebPartClientScript' in type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermProperty' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' cannot reduce access.

I have tried doing iisreset, restart SQL Server and SharePoint and even restarted machine but no luck.

Tried to run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard and even that fails on Step 2 with following message.

> Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence. An exception of type
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown. 
>   Additional exception information: Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.

How do I fix this issue?

**EDIT**

OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

**EDIT**

### Following is the list of updates that were installed. One of them cause the problem. How to identify it?

Security Update for Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package (KB2538243)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2479943)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2656356)
Update for the 2007 Microsoft Office System (KB967642)
Update for Microsoft Office 2007 System (KB2539530)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2727528)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2719033)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2736422)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2847927)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2840631)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2861698)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2892074)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2893294)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2862330)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2912390)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2911501)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2929733)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2871997)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2931356)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2957189)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2973351)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2973201)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2937610)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2943357)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2976897)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2993651)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2972211)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2973112)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2894844)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB2972216)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2968294)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2972100)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB2972107)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2977292)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2984972)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2991963)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB2978128)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3005607)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3010788)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2978120)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3003743)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3011780)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2992611)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3019978)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3020388)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3022777)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3021674)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3004375)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3004361)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3000483)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3033929)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3033889)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3035132)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3030377)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3035126)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3042553)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3046269)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3045685)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB3037574)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB3037581)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3020369)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3055642)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB3023215)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB3023224)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3031432)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3059317)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3067903)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3072630)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3068457)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3075226)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3046017)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3060716)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3071756)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3075220)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3076895)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3076949)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3078601)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3084135)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB3074230)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB3074543)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB3074550)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3086255)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3087039)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3080446)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3042058)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3101722)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3092601)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB3097989)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB3098781)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 x64 (KB3097996)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3108381)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3108670)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3109103)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3108371)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3109094)
Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2881067)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3108664)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3109560)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3110329)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3124001)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3123479)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2506928)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2545698)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2547666)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB982018)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2563227)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2603229)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2607047)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2636573)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2660075)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2640148)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2608658)
Security Update for Report Viewer Redistributable 2008 (KB971118)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (KB972221)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (KB972222)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 XML Editor (KB2251487)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package (KB2538242)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (KB2669970)
Security Update for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package (KB2565063)
Update for Best Practices Analyzer for Application Server for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2386667)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2719857)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2732059)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2729094)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2750841)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2763523)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2761217)
Update for Kernel-Mode Driver Framework version 1.11 for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2685811)
Update for User-Mode Driver Framework version 1.11 for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2685813)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2726535)
Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2726954) 64-Bit Edition
Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2760224) 64-Bit Edition
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2791765)
Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2768016) 64-Bit Edition
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2574819)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2592687)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2853952)
Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2817490) 64-Bit Edition
Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2738038) 64-Bit Edition
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2834140)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2888049)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2808679)
Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB2827239) 64-Bit Edition
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2893519)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2515325)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2647753)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2891804)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB2830477)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2843630)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2923545)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2908783)
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (KB2938806)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2852386)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2800095)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2966583)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2985461)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2970228)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3006121)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3006137)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3013531)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3020370)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3054476)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3068708)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3040272)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3054205)
Security Update for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 (KB3045313)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3092627)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3075249)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3078667)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3080149)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3080079)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3107998)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3112148)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3102429)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3133043)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64 (KB3122648)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB3122656)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3115858)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3126587)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64 (KB3127220)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3124280)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB3127229)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64 (KB3072305)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3118401)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3121255)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3138612)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3138910)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3139940)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3138962)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64 (KB3135983)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 7, Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB3135996)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3139398)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3139914)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3140735)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3133977)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3137061)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3138901)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3139923)
Definition Update for Microsoft Office 2013 (KB3114942) 64-Bit Edition
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3146963)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3146706)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3149090)
Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 11 for Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB3148198)
Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3147071)
Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB3145739)
Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64 (KB3142042)
Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB3114542)
Definition Update for Windows Defender - KB915597 (Definition 1.217.1307.0)

Comment: Added more information in question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem many run into when upgrading Project Server 2013 to SP1 without upgrading SharePoint.
Solution seems to be to upgrade SharePoint 2013 to SP1

Comment: I am not using Project Server 2013 only SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Do not forget to update your language packs as well. I got that same error, when I did forget them.

Comment: How can I update language pack? I am only using English.